# Using Python's regex .match() method to get the string before and after an underscore

Tags: python, regex, string, iterator

I have the following code:

```
tablesInDataset = ["henry_jones_12345678", "henry_jones", "henry_jones_123"]

for table in tablesInDataset:
    tableregex = re.compile("\d{8}")
    tablespec = re.match(tableregex, table)

    everythingbeforedigits = tablespec.group(0)
    digits = tablespec.group(1)
```

My regex should only return the string if it contains 8 digits after an underscore. Once it returns the string, I want to use `.match()` to get two groups using the `.group()` method. The first group should contain a string will all of the characters before the digits and the second should contain a string with the 8 digits.

What is the correct regex to get the results I am looking for using `.match()` and `.group()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tableregex = re.compile("(.*)_(\d{8})")
```

Answer (score 5):

Use capture groups:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(?P<name>.*)_(?P<number>\d{8})')
>>> pat.findall(s)
[('henry_jones', '12345678')]
```

You get the nice feature of named groups, if you want it:

```
>>> match = pat.match(s)
>>> match.groupdict()
{'name': 'henry_jones', 'number': '12345678'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this pattern should match what you need: `(.*?_)(\d{8})`.

First group includes everything up to the 8 digits, including the underscore. Second group is the 8 digits.

If you don't want the underscore included, use this instead: `(.*?)_(\d{8})`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
import re

tablesInDataset = ["henry_jones_12345678", "henry_jones", "henry_jones_123"]
rx = re.compile(r'^(\D+)_(\d{8})$')

matches = [(match.groups()) \
            for item in tablesInDataset \
            for match in [rx.search(item)] \
            if match]
print(matches)
```

Better than any *dot-star-soup* :)